# Browse an image in html

Tags: javascript, html, button

i am making a form in html which have to browse an image from the folder but i donot know how to do that the code i tried is

Html

```
<tr>
<td>*PHOTO</td>
<td><img border="0" src="image.jpg" alt="NOT VALID" width="340" height="220">
</td>
</tr>
```

don't know how to use browse button and write a script for it in Js

Comment: There is no form there. No button. Please edit your question because it is not clear at all, and show us more code.

Answer (score 2):

Quite a basic question that you can solve with some Googling

Example:

- http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
- [HTML code to upload images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692454/html-code-to-upload-images)
- http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3877766/Web-Developer-How-To-Upload-Images-Using-PHP.htm